# Qt Include Path

Tags: c++, qt, include-path

I am trying to include my header files but qt see the main directory of my header files. I've tried this:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/MyLib/inc
```

And my header file is in this directory:

```
C:/MyLib/inc/MyLib/myheader.h
```

In my Qt project I can only access my header file like this:

```
#include <MyLib/inc/MyLib/myheader.h>
```

But I want this:

```
#include <MyLib/myheader.h>
```

Why the accessible directory is the main directory, how can I fix this?

edit: I've recognized now, Qt gives me error "No such file or directory" with both includes.

Comment: try with "inc/myheader.h"

Comment: It doesn't work and it doesn't seem rational.

Comment: Try `#include "MyLib/myheader.h"`. There's a difference between angle brackets and quotation marks.

Comment: Have you re-run `qmake` after each change to the `.pro` file?

Answer (score 0):

Rerunning qmake worked, thanks to Kuba Ober.